# TiniMCE draggable toolbar in inline mode

Tags: jquery, tinymce

Is it possible to assign jQuery draggable() to tinyMce toolbar in inline mode:

```
$('.row').tinymce({
    inline: true,
    schema: "html5",
    menubar:false,
    toolbar: "bold italic alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify bullist numlist code fullscreen",
    plugins: [
        "advlist code fullscreen",
    ],
});
```

By the way, I'm using v4 with jQuery plugin.